# "Detailed answers to any questions you might have" wording improvement

Tags: discussion

The wording for the Help Center has always struck me as particularly...unhelpful. Could it be reconsidered?

[image]

My usual use case is I'm trying to find out what is on- and off-topic for a given site. None of the options in this list seem like the right one, but I've learnt from experience that it's not "Tour" (the most intuitive guess). So by elimination, it must be "Help Center".

The specific issues:

- Every Stack site is essentially, a place to come for "help" and "answers to ... questions". This text really should be conveying that Help Center is where you go for questions *about* the site, not your general subject-matter questions.
- Most of the answers actually aren't detailed at all. For details, you need to go to Meta. Help Center only contains very high level bullet points.
- The "any" and "you might have" is a redundant waste of four words. How is the phrase materially different from "Detailed answers to questions"?
- It implies you can ask questions there. Which, unlike so many other places in the Stack Exchange network (ie, the site itself, its meta, meta.se, and chat), you can't.

Alternative suggestions:

- How to use <site name>
- What you need to know about <site name>
- Rules and FAQs for <site name>
- Help using <site name>

### Update

To spell out more the ambiguity about "question" and "answer" let's look at a bigger screenshot:

[image]

These words appear several times:

- Top "Questions" at the top
- N "Answers" next to each row in the main content
- "Question Close Update" on the right hand side
- "Detailed answers to any questions you might have" on the right hand side popup

IMHO there is very little about the last one that distinguishes it from the others enough that you would obviously know that these questions and answers are *different* from all the others. Even changing the word to "Detailed answers to questions about this site" would be so much clearer.

Comment: Your *solution* is to dilute the text and its claim that the Help Center is *actually* helpful. Some Help Centers are fairly helpful, there are dozens that are not; they contain the default template and say 'figure it out'. Rather than water down the text it would be better if each help was edited (by the moderators) to reflect the results of each site's discussion on their per-site-meta about the scope of the site. --- 1st point: split hairs, 2nd point: True, 3rd point: Maybe, 4th: Not really. --- You *could* suggest that to graduate the site's Help must be reasonable (edited); being NIMBY.

Comment: Honestly not hair-splitting: every time I see that text I have go through a process of "isn't the whole site about answers to questions? Ohhhh...".

Comment: Re your first comment: I wish that "template text" and site-specific text were not mingled. I'm always looking for the site-specific bit, and having to skim through everything that looks generic. I don't need helping using an SE site, I need help knowing how *this* site differs from all the others.

Comment: Steve, the *idea* the Help Center contains the answer to each question that someone could ask (about *anything*) is unique. A better interpretation is: The Help Center should provide help for using the site. Much like the "About" page isn't about everything, only about here. --- As to your second comment: Every site has this page: [https://meta.stackexchange.com/ **help/on-topic**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), with the start of that URL different for each site and the ending the same. That page is ***supposed to*** contain good information, after the template is edited.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're debating my feedback about how I interpret the description of the Help Center every time I see it. Obviously it's not correct. But it's what those words convey to me in that context (even though I know better). Simililarly, giving me more context about the intent behind a design isn't really relevant to my feedback about why, as a user, that design isn't really working for me.